# What's the simplest way to connect two containers without Docker compose?

Tags: docker, networking, bridge

Considering the fact I cannot use `Docker compose` and a very simple `Docker` setup:

- a NodeJs app (container `A`)
- a service exposing a REST api (container `B`)

How can I connect to `B` from `A` to query the API without SSHing but just in appending stuff to `docker run...` ?

I've succeeded in getting internal ip of `B` (using `docker container inspect B`) and requesting from `A` something like `fetch("http://ip-of-b/api")`. It works but it's not well-down. Indeed if I make another deploy, `B` ip changes.

Is there a very simple way to make a *production bridge* between these 2 containers?
I've read about `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` but I can't understand how it works/it's relevant.

PS: in the future, I might have a third container (`C`) that must also be able to connect to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

> I've succeeded in getting internal ip of B (using docker container inspect B) and requesting from A something like fetch("http://ip-of-b/api").

That solution is problematic because container ips are dynamic; if you were to restart one of the two containers, you would no longer be able to connect. You want to use container *names*.

It's important to realize that Docker Compose is just a convenient wrapper around the docker API; you can accomplish exactly the same thing using `docker run`. When you bring up a Docker Compose application stack, Compose starts by creating a user-defined network, and then it subsequently attaches all the containers to that network. That's important because containers on a user defined network are able to refer to eachother by name.

We can do the same thing with `docker run`. First create a network:

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

Then launch one container attached to that network:

```
docker run --name app1 --network=mynetwork app1-image
```

And then launch a second container:

```
docker run --name app2 --network=mynetwork app2-image
```

Now within the `app1` container you can use the hostname `app2` to refer to the second container, and in the `app2` container you can use the hostname `app1` to refer to the first container. Here's a simple, runnable example:

```
docker network create mynetwork
docker run -d --name app1 --network mynetwork docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
docker run -d --name app2 --network mynetwork docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
docker run -d --name app3 --network mynetwork docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

Taking container `app1` as an example, we can successfully access our services the appropriate container names. The following commands all run successfully:

```
docker exec app1 wget -O- http://app1:8080
docker exec app1 wget -O- http://app2:8080
docker exec app1 wget -O- http://app3:8080
```

You can read more about this in the [Docker networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/).